# Is there any Hierarchy among Wizards

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit

From the movies and the books, it is clear that Saruman was the head of the wizarding order (before his demotion) and Gandalf was second. But there were three more wizards. Are there any references to Hierarchy among these five Wizards in Tolkien's work? I want to know the order of their seniority in terms of power and knowledge.

Comment: Briefly no, there isn't; and in fact Saruman isn't so much head of the order of wizards as he is of the White Council. But at my phone it's hard to make this a good answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Who replaced Gandalf as the Grey Wizard?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84280/who-replaced-gandalf-as-the-grey-wizard). The question is not the same, but the accepted answer also answers this question.

Comment: It's clear, though, that Saruman desired that there be a hierarchy, with him at the top. We know this because he accused Gandalf of desiring that very honor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, no.  Even if there was it would not be very relevant.  The Blue Wizards spent all their time in the east, having no contact other three and Radagast tending to do his own thing, not getting involved with Saruman/Gandalf/The White Council.

Comment: and it seems each of the wizards approached their task along the lines of their strengths.  Radagast through animals.  Sauroman through wit and guile.  Gandalf by building relationships between him and the rulers of Middle Earth and between the different rulers and also gathering and disseminating military intelligence.