# Why were there two blue wizards?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, istari

In *The Lord of the Rings*, we know of the five Istari sent to Middle-earth to help resist Sauron. There was Saruman, the White; Gandalf, the Grey; Radagast, the Brown; and Alatar and Pallando, the Blue.

As per [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/146348/124167), we know that the Blue wizards seemed to have traveled together to the East, and that their mission seemed to have been unsuccessful.

The question is--why were they both blue? Saruman is white; Gandalf is grey; Radagast is brown. Why were the remaining two the same color?

I'd be curious about answers both in-universe and out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the symbolism of the colors assigned to Istari wizards?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6283/what-is-the-symbolism-of-the-colors-assigned-to-istari-wizards), cf [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6296/98028) which posits it's because of their Vala alignment

Comment: Because JRRT said there were "five" wizards, and having a place in the story for only three, he had to make something up when everyone started asking who the other two were.

Answer (score 1):

Alatar was the original one to be sent, and Pallando came with him as his friend.  This close connection is probably the only reason we can find for their choosing the same color.

Tolkien himself in his letters repeatedly described them as not very fleshed out.

Comment: It would be good to back up your answer with some of these letters of Tolkien. As it stands this answer is a bit light on details and almost looks more like a comment.